# Creating a pointer to a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I know that if I use a base class, I can effectively create a pointer to a templated class. Is there an easier way?

So. Here is an example using a base class

```
class A {}
template <class T>
class B : public A {}
```

Now, I can create an instance of `B<T>` and point to it using the base class `A`. Is there an easier way? A more direct way? One that doesn't involve creating a "dummy" base class.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?  You want an instance of class B to be able to point to another instance of class B?  If that's all you're trying to do, there are other, simpler ways to implement something like that.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot just use a void*?

Comment: Yes. I would have to know what the type of the variable really is to coerce it back before calling a method on it and that isn't easy in the context I'm using it.

Comment: But A doesn't have any virtual functions, so I don't see how it will work (and if it has virtual functions, it really isn't a dummy class anymore).

Answer (score 3):

Different instances of your template — say, `B<int>` and `B<char>` — are completely separate types, just like `int` and `char` are separate types.  You can't have a single pointer that can point to *either* type of object unless you derive them both from the same base class, as in your example.  Just like you can't have a single pointer variable that can point to either an `int` or a `char`.

But if you only want your pointer to point to a single specific type, you can just declare a pointer of type `B<int> *` or `B<char> *` or whatever.  You don't need the base class `A` for that.

That single specific type might be specified as an argument of some other template, of course.  For example, you could have a template class `C<T>`, which contains a pointer of type `B<T> *`, so a `C<int>` will have a `B<int> *` member and a `C<char>` will have a `B<char> *` member.  Once again, you don't need the `A` base class for that.

Comment: I was just worried that I was missing something. In the end, it would require auto-generating effectively a base class. Probably not a good idea.

Comment: What do you need a "generated" base class for?  As another comment said, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Sounds like something strange.